# Download only relevant columns in locust csv

Tags: csv, format, locust

While trying to download the results from locust the data is getting downloaded with following headers:
Type    Name    Timestamp   # requests  # failures  Requests/s  Requests Failed/s   Median response time    Average response time   Min response time   Max response time   Average Content Size    50% 66% 75% 80% 90% 95% 98% 99% 99.90%  99.99%  99.999  100%
I just want the relevant values (not the % one). Is there any way to download the required columns only in locust?

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not an option at present (June 2020).

You can see by yourself how this is solved in the [code](https://github.com/locustio/locust/blob/e7758991e1b0616015b269d913eaaad84fdb3398/locust/web.py#L174). You're always writing [percentiles](https://github.com/locustio/locust/blob/e7758991e1b0616015b269d913eaaad84fdb3398/locust/stats.py#L786) into the exported csv file.

Comment: I want to make a chart out of the csv results for my test reports but due to these percentage I'm not able to create a interactive chart. It is looking messy with it.

Comment: What percentile exactly depict here?

Comment: I suppose you can always delete the unwanted columns, hide them, or simply don't take them into account. I don't see a reason why either option is not possible.

Comment: Yeah i have to think of another way. Have you got any idea why percentiles are stored in csv?

Comment: Why not? It's another piece of information you get from your load tests, so I suppose some people find them useful. As I said, just ignore them in one way or the other.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow these steps (considering you are already using Locust, I hope rest of your project is in python):

1. get the default csv files with all the columns
2. use pandas dataframe to read the csv and then filter only those columns you are interested in.
3. create graph using matplotlib or other python graph libraries

See below a graph I created using the above process. It includes only the min, median and p99 response times

[image: locust_stats_graph]

Comment: Thanks for sharing this, my project is in java and I'm using locust4j. Please let me know if I can do the same in java as well.

Comment: Yes, you can do that absolutely. After the tests are run, read the csv using java code and modify it as you like. But, I am unaware of any nice graph libraries comparable to what we have in python

Comment: Sure I'll give it try. For creating graph I'm using jfreechart in java

Comment: Yes, it worked. But if got to know that the percentiles in load testing csv results are very important part and the graph is supposed to be made by them. Bt it was worth the try

Comment: glad to hear it. If possible can you please give an upvote or accept the answer if it satisfied your question. Thanks